how do I read messages in open groups? telethon
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = '?????'
api_hash = '????????'

with TelegramClient('sync', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    chat_entity = client.get_entity('https://t.me/new_ton_news')
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat_entity):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)

telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetHistoryRequest)

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some details to your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
